# The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm suddenly getting this error in my WP8 project, which seems to originate from generated code.  I have a previous working version and the App.xaml is identical.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bins" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

and the LocalisedStrings.vb file is intact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem when compiling the standard *Windows Phone Databound App* template.
Following steps worked for me:

- close all Visual Studio instances
- if your *Region settings* in the control panel mismatch the Windows Phone SDK's language (e.g. German), set the Format in the Region settings to *English (United States)*
- in your windows explorer, navigate to **`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\`** and delete the contents of the folders **`10.0`** and **`11.0`**
- reopen Visual Studio and **rebuild** your project

Comment: This also worked for me, as I had the same problem just after upgradind my wp7 app to wp8.

Comment: As a variation, i tried it the other way 'round: Setting my project locales to the same as my system (i did not want to change my system's region settings). My approach did NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue. the root cause for my problem is as below.

1) I referenced below in my code. but i haven't added the library( System.Xml.Serialization.xml). Add Reference and select System.Xml.Serialization.xml to include the dll.

```
System.Xml.Serialization
```

2) I use an usercontrol called FileList.xaml in the mainwindow

**FileList.xaml**

```
<AM:time2str x:Key="time2str"/>
```

But i didnt add the class which inherits from IMultiValueConverter

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**(I missed the following code)

```
public class time2str : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ********************
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this error after downloading and installing a fresh Visual Studio 2012 (the initial release version) and trying to build the default blank Windows Phone template project straight out of the box - it was only resolved by updating Visual Studio 2012 Express to [Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48708).

Answer (score 0):

I had this message when the mobile project platform was "ARM", I changed to "any CPU".

Go to:

- Solution Project / Properties
- Configuration Properties / configuration
- Click in mobile project / Platform / "Any CPU".
- Clean the project and run again