# VS 2013 The name “LocalizedStrings” does not exist in the namespace

Tags: windows-phone-8, namespaces

My question exactly looks like this one :
[The name "LocalizedStrings" does not exist in the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226112/the-name-localizedstrings-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)

Except that the answers i tried didn't work with me.

I'm using visual studio 2013 and windows 8.1 enterprise (fresh install).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just added a new answer to the question you link to - I was also working on a fresh install (of Visual Studio 2012 Express), deleting CoreCon cache files didn't solve the issue for me either. The only solution I found that worked was updating Visual Studio to the latest Update (Update 5).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Repairing Visual studio did the Trick!

Answer (score 2):

Close Visual Studio.
Than, delete sub folders 10.0 and 11.0 from "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\"
Open Visual Studio and rebuild solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue in VS 2013 for a Windows Phone 8 project. In my case one of the packages (Nokia imaging SDK to be precise) had to use ARM architecture. All I had to do is to change my solution's configuration manager.

- Right click on your solution file in VS, select properties
- In "Configuration Properties", select "Configuration Manager"
- Now select the solution platform you need to use for builds on your solution.

Hope this helps you.